# How do I access the admin console for Orbeon Forms Runner

Tags: orbeon

I have installed Orbeon Forms and can create forms, but it seems all I can do in forms runner is actually access the form, it does not seem that I have access to build some of the dynamic content that I see referenced. How do I go about accessing the admin side of form runner?

Comment: I think you are referring to Form Builder, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Orbeon Forms on your local machine, on port 8080, and kept the default context name of `orbeon` for the web app, you typically you can go to the following URL to create a new form in Form Builder:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/new
```